# Json first object is a *, how to get it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

If I run:

```
$("#results ul").append(data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return "<li>" + val.lang + "</li>" }));
```

I get all correct values of `lang` but I need to get the first object and it doesn't have a verbal naming but it has

> *

So when I try to access it like `val.*` I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/zt3ssajd/612/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access your object like this: `val['*']` .

Comment: ha! No way, I was using double `" "` ! Thank you

Comment: Double quotes work as well, both are valid string delimiters.

Comment: @DarthJDG yes sure but it was within a `.append` which was already using `double quotes`. Sight!

Comment: I meant on my real case scenario not on here as we don't have `double quotes` on the `.append` used on the question on here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use bracket notation when accessing objects containing special characters:

```
return val['*'] + "</li>";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/fg395Lp9/

It's also worth noting that you need to use bracket notation when accessing an object using a variable or a reserved keyword (thanks to @DarthJDG for pointing that out):

```
var foo = '*';
return val[foo];
```

Furthermore, if you are exploring some newer aspects of JavaScript, computed property names incorporate bracket notation:

https://ryanpcmcquen.org/javascript/2016/10/25/computed-property-names-are-awesome.html

Comment: Worth noting that you also need to use bracket notation if the property name is a reserved keyword, e.g. `class`.

Comment: Thank you @DarthJDG, I have added that.

Comment: @DarthJDG does it mean it should be `val['lang']` rather than `val.lang`?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen the above answer has no quotes, would it work the same?

Comment: @rob.m, no `val.lang` is perfectly valid since there are no breaking special characters. It is a _valid_ identifier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: @rob.m, when using bracket notation without quotes, you are providing a variable. I expanded my example to make that more obvious.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen perfect, makes sense. Thanks for this

Comment: @rob.m you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is the same as the others, but with a bit more explanation...

```
val["*"]  // Bracket notation
```

Objects in JavaScript are really not too much more than dictionaries, groupings of key/value pairs or, said another way, associative arrays.

As such, you are always able to access an object's property (a.k.a. key) by passing a string as an index to the object. But, if the index/key/property name does not contain any illegal language identifier characters, then you can use the more common "dot notation".

Taking this to an extreme, most people would probably say that an object property name could not contain spaces because, of course, this wouldn't compile and doesn't seem to make any sense:

```
 obj.some property name = "10";    // won't compile
```

But, you actually can have a property name that contains spaces if you think of the object as an array and the property name as a key:

```
 obj["some property name"] = 10;  // perfectly fine
```

This also opens up some great opportunities for dynamic code because it allows for you to pass a key (string) dynamically:

```js
var keyName = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    
var obj = {};
obj[keyName] = "some value";
     
for(var prop in obj){ 
     console.log("The obj." + prop + " property has a value of: " + obj[prop]);
}
```